# How to calculate and plot multiple spectrogram in a for loop with librosa?

Tags: python, for-loop, librosa, spectrogram

I have a 16-sec audio signal. I want to divide my signal into 16 1-sec signals with a for loop and calculate its spectrogram. Let's assume the raw signal is like the figure that I have attached and I want to calculate and plot the spectrogram of each segment with a for loop exactly like the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Ge7.png)

I appreciate your help in advance.

The code that I used to plot the 1-sec signals is:

```
ncols = 4
nrows = len(segment) // ncols + (len(segment) % ncols > 0) # finding the best number of rows to plot the segments

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22,19))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5,wspace=0.4)
plt.suptitle('Raw segmented signal \n \n', fontweight = 'bold',size = 20)

for i in range (0,16):
    plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, i+1)
    plt.plot(segment[i])
    plt.title('Segment: ' + str(i+1), fontweight = 'bold',size = 15)
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude (mV)', fontweight = 'bold')
    plt.xlabel('Samples',fontweight = 'bold')
    plt.ylim([-1.5, 1.5])
    plt.xlim(xmin = 0, xmax = len(segment[i]))
    fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer that might help.  It uses np.split to divide the 16 second clip into the 1 second clips so there's a built-in assumption that the clip is 16 seconds long (i.e. it won't divide a clip of an arbitrary length into 1-second pieces) but since your question is specifically about getting 16 one second clips from a 16 second clip, maybe it is enough:

```
import numpy as np
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

NCOLS = 4
NROWS = 4

FILENAME = 'sound.wav'
sound, rate = librosa.load(FILENAME, sr=None)

segments = np.split(sound, NCOLS*NROWS)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22, 19))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=0.4)
plt.suptitle('Raw segmented signal \n \n', fontweight='bold', size=20)

for i in range (0, NROWS * NCOLS):
    plt.subplot(NROWS, NCOLS, i + 1)
    plt.plot(segments[i])
    plt.title('Segment: ' + str(i + 1), fontweight='bold', size=15)
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude (mV)', fontweight='bold')
    plt.xlabel('Samples', fontweight='bold')
    plt.ylim([-1.5, 1.5])
    plt.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=len(segments[i]))
    fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

So that will plot the waveforms and then for the spectrograms you can run this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22,19))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5,wspace=0.4)
plt.suptitle('Spectrograms of segments \n \n', fontweight='bold', size=20)

for i in range (0, NROWS * NCOLS):
    plt.subplot(NROWS, NCOLS, i + 1)
    plt.specgram(segments[i], Fs=rate)
    plt.title('Segment: ' + str(i + 1), fontweight='bold', size=15)
    fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

If you *did* want to split out a clip of arbitrary length into 1-second clips you could replace the np.split line above with:

```
segments = [sound[i:i+rate] for i in range(0, len(sound), rate)]
```

This works because `rate` is equivalent to the number of samples in one second.  You'd have to do something more if you were looking for a different clip length.  Note: the last segment won't be equal to a full second if the original clip was not actually divisible by whole seconds. Other note: lots of the rest of this code assumes you end up with 16 segments.

The original question did suggest that the spectrogram be computed with librosa and a follow-on comment clarified that the hope was that the spectrogram be computed solely using librosa instead of with pyplot.specgram.  Here is an example for doing this (note: seemed to be noticeably slower than using pyplot.spectrogram on my computer):

```
def specgram_librosa(segment, rate, ax, win_length=256, hop_length=64):
    D = librosa.stft(segment, hop_length=hop_length, win_length=win_length)
    S_db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(D), ref=np.max)
    img = librosa.display.specshow(S_db,
                                   sr=rate,
                                   x_axis='s',
                                   y_axis='linear',
                                   ax=ax)

    return img


fig, ax = plt.subplots(NROWS, NCOLS, figsize=(22, 19))
ax = ax.flatten()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=0.4)
plt.suptitle('Spectrograms of segments \n \n', fontweight='bold', size=20)

for i in range (0, NROWS * NCOLS):
    ax[i].set_title('Segment: ' + str(i + 1), fontweight='bold', size=15)
    img = specgram_librosa(segments[i], rate, ax[i])
    fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax[i], format="%+2.f dB")
    fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to use librosa.spectrogram instead of plt.specgram??

Comment: @MalahatMehraban Does librosa have librosa.spectrogram?  I had a tiny look and I didn't see it but did see librosa.melspectrogram? In case it is helpful, added code in my answer for using librosa to calculate the spectrogram. No promises that it is an efficient way to do this :-).  I also have probably not matched the spectrogram parameters such that you'll get exactly the same output as from plt.specgram.

Comment: The code works well, thank you for your help, I appreciate it.